# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT eliminate duplicates when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101ef3/4)

**Problem:**

Since I'm joining two tables - `prices` and `videos`, `GROUP_CONCAT()` duplicates values for every row joined by the second `LEFT JOIN`.

**My attempt:**

```sql
SELECT
    `Cat`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Price`.`id`, "") ORDER BY `Price`.`price`) AS `PriceId`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Price`.`price`, "") ORDER BY `Price`.`price`) AS `PricePrice`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Vid`.`id`, "") ORDER BY `Vid`.`id`) AS `VideoId`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Vid`.`uuid`, "") ORDER BY `Vid`.`id`) AS `VideoUUID`
FROM
    `categories` AS `Cat`
LEFT JOIN `prices` AS `Price` ON `Cat`.`id`=`Price`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `videos` AS `Vid` ON `Cat`.`id`=`Vid`.`category_id`
GROUP BY
    `Cat`.`id`
```

**Question:**

How do I tweak the query, so `PricePrice`, `VideoId`, `VideoUUID` columns in SQLFiddle output do not contain duplicates?

I did try adding `DISTINCT` inside of `GROUP_CONCAT`, but that does not help, as it would filter out duplicate values that I should preserve (like, `price`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joining three tables a good solution is to use *scalar subqueries*. For example:

```
select
  *,
  (select group_concat(p.id order by p.price) 
   from prices p where p.category_id = c.id) as PriceId,
  (select group_concat(p.price order by p.price) 
   from prices p where p.category_id = c.id) as PricePrice,
  (select group_concat(v.id order by v.id) 
   from videos v where v.category_id = c.id) as VideoId,
  (select group_concat(v.uuid order by v.id) 
   from videos v where v.category_id = c.id) as VideoUUID
from categories c
group by id
```

Result:

```
id  token                PriceId     PricePrice           VideoId      VideoUUID                           
--- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- ------------ ----------------------------------- 
1   Wyatt Reinger (ZW)   2,1,3       2.51,2.61,4.45       1,2,3,4      3a817d01,3222679e,63cdc038,e8d8edf4 
2   Donna Cronin (BL)    4           4.76                 5            93f8a404                            
3   Ally Kertzmann (GY)  5,6         1.83,1.84            6,7,8        6f2459a7,463127ab,4bf357ba          
4   Talia Torp (AF)      7,8         2.61,3.32            9,10,11,12   0cedbd0a,8b21afd7,ea616692,ed2b10d7 
5   Delphine Lakin (TL)  11,12,9,10  1.65,3.27,3.27,3.36  13,14,15,16  6217a488,7f52a97a,de11ba64,b49b6ddc
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101ef3/8).

The problem of joining three tables is that it produces many duplicate values that complicate the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to accept that not every problem should be solved in a single query. In this case, you can avoid the Cartesian product between the two joined tables by doing two separate queries:

```
SELECT
    `Cat`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Price`.`id`, "") ORDER BY `Price`.`price`) AS `PriceId`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Price`.`price`, "") ORDER BY `Price`.`price`) AS `PricePrice`,
FROM
    `categories` AS `Cat`
LEFT JOIN `prices` AS `Price` ON `Cat`.`id`=`Price`.`category_id`
GROUP BY
    `Cat`.`id`;

SELECT
    `Cat`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Vid`.`id`, "") ORDER BY `Vid`.`id`) AS `VideoId`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`Vid`.`uuid`, "") ORDER BY `Vid`.`id`) AS `VideoUUID`
FROM
    `categories` AS `Cat`
LEFT JOIN `videos` AS `Vid` ON `Cat`.`id`=`Vid`.`category_id`
GROUP BY
    `Cat`.`id`;
```